# Update Url String

Tags: android, string, url

what ways can I update this url string without having to open or upgrade the .apk file? can I update it from a twitter post or something? I just don't want to have to keep updating the app everytime I want to change the channel, but I do need to change the channel some 5 times a day. Here is some code:

```
video_url = "my url link - this being the link i need to update"; 
     try {
                final VideoView videoView =(VideoView)findViewById(R.id.videoView1);
                mediaController = new MediaController(ServerActivity.this);
                mediaController.setAnchorView(videoView);
                // Set video link (mp4 format )
                Uri video = Uri.parse(video_url);
                videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);
                videoView.setVideoURI(video);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would retrieve the url via a RSS feed.

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/x-android/index.html

Answer (score 1):

Keep URLs in persistant storage, such as `SharedPreferences` and load the appropriate URL from it according tho the channel you want to change to.

Comment: It depends on some parameters that I don't know about your environment / code. I would start here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html